# Send Output direct to HTML or through XML first?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am writing a parser to parse incoming text files.  I have it to where it will parse everything accurately.

I have an option for it to output to text - this was done to check the accuracy of the parsing.  I am currently implementing an option to write to a spreadsheet but it doesn't output everything yet.

I have a request to output as static HTML.  **Is it worth outputting to XML and then generating HTML from that?**

I see C# has the `XMLTransform` class which looks like it would do what I need.  Is using the XML designer in VS and writing the XSLT file easier than hand-coding all of the HTML output?   I know Excel will import XML files, but it is a little messy and I don't get the formatting options I can get if I generate the `.xls` file directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give you a qualified No.

It is *generally* not worth building XML then running it through an XSLT transformation to build HTML.

That said, I *might* consider such an option if I wanted to easily swap out transformations, such as if this is an app used by multiple clients and the generated HTML would be client dependent.  Even then I'd investigate using a simple tokenized HTML template in which I just plugged in the data I wanted.  However, if the transformation was sufficiently complex then, yes, I'd go the XSLT route.

The reason for the No is that by the conversion adds such a level of complexity that it is usually not worth the time involved.

Comment: thanks.  I really don't know how complex it will be to build the HTML.  I don't anticipate anyone else using this - just myself and my team here.  I will look at output direct to HTML, either by some generator or just tell the switch class how to build an HTML representation of itself.

Comment: I found the HtmlTextWriterClass.  I will look into using that to generate the HTML.  It looks to be easier than the spreadsheet.